# is there an algorithm to reverse a chosen part of a number?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I want to reverse a number but in a way that user chooses
user determine a range which we should reverse digits in that range
for example we want reverse of 123456 and digit range is 2 to 4 which includes {2,3,4}
so user answer would be 143256

*I want a solution which does not use arrays and string*.
It would be my pleasure to know your ideas..

Comment: What have you tried so far? What doesn't work with your current solution?

Comment: Sounds vague. And you didn't provide any code. What happens when I reverse 123454321345 between 3 and 4? Which 3? Which 4?

Comment: @sleepToken
answer would be 124354321345

Comment: Hi and welcome, please read on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, please provide some code

Comment: This screams of a homework question

Answer (score 3):

Reversing part of a number or entire number is not a math operation that can be done with Integers/Longs, so you can use `String`s.

Convert your number to a `StringBuilder`, there is a `reverse()` method there.
You can cut the `String` with `substring()` method also. After cutting and reversing, concatenate again.

EDIT: It can be done with just numbers that way:

Step 1 — Isolate the last digit in number:

`lastDigit = number % 10`

Step 2 — Append lastDigit to reverse

`reverse = (reverse * 10) + lastDigit`

Step 3 - Remove last digit from number

`number = number / 10`

Step 4 - Iterate this process

`while (number > 0)`

Source: https://medium.com/@ManBearPigCode/how-to-reverse-a-number-mathematically-97c556626ec6

Comment: thanks

but I not allowed to use arrays nor strings

Comment: @MohammadhosseinArsalan, check edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int reverseFonction(int startRange, int endRange, int number) {
       String numberString = String.valueOf(number);
       int numberLength = numberString.length();
       if(startRange > numberLength -1  ||
          endRange > numberLength - 1  || 
          endRange <= startRange ||
          startRange < 1) {
          return number;
       }else {
           String string1 = StringUtils.substring(0, startRange -1);
           String string2 = StringUtils.substring(startRange, endRange-1);
           String string3 = StringUtils.substring(endRange, numberLength -1);

           String string2_reversed = "";
           for(int i= numberLength-1; i>=0; i--) {
               string2_reversed += string2.charAt(i);
            }

           String finalNumberString = string1 + string2_reversed + string3;
           return Integer.parseInt(finalNumberString);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int N = 123456;
    int start = 2;
    int end = 4;
    start--; // making offset as index position
    end--; // making offset as index position

    String numString = String.valueOf(N);
    char[] array = numString.toCharArray();

    while(start<end){
        char temp = array[start];
        // swap to reverse
        array[start] = array[end];
        array[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }

    String resNum ="";
    for (char ch: array) {
        resNum += ch;
    }

    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(resNum));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that numbers are non-strings, then this example uses a long as it holds more digits.

```
        long n = 123456789L;
        System.out.println(n + " " + reverse(n, 1, 9));
        n = 1;
        System.out.println(n + " " + reverse(n, 1, 1));
        n = 11123567111L;
        System.out.println(n + " " + reverse(n, 4, 8));
        n = 23;
        System.out.println(n + " " + reverse(n, 1, 2));



    public static long reverse(long n, int s, int e) {  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String str = Long.toString(n);
        if (s < 1 || e > str.length() || s > e) {
            System.out.println("Improper indices provided");
            return -1;
        }
        return Long.parseLong(str.substring(0, s-1)
                + new StringBuilder(str.substring(s-1, e)).reverse()
                + str.substring(e));

    }
```

The range is specified according to what you asked.  However, normal ranges in Java are zero based and `[s,e)` where `s` is included and `e` is excluded.

Since you updated your question to state that Strings and arrays may not be used, here is a math based alternative.

```
        long v = 111112456788888L; // number to process
        int s = 6; // starting point of reversible section
        int e = 10;// ending point of reversible section

        // total digits in number
        int digits = (int) Math.log10(v) + 1;

        // divisor of the tail part
        long tdiv = (long) Math.pow(10, digits - e);

        // divisor of the center part.
        long cdiv = (long) Math.pow(10, e - s + 1);

        long tail = v % tdiv;
        v /= tdiv;
        long ctr = v % cdiv;
        v /= cdiv;

        // reverse the middle section.
        long rev = 0;
        while (ctr > 0) {
            rev = rev * 10 + ctr % 10;
            ctr /= 10;
        }
        long result = ((v * cdiv) + rev) * tdiv + tail;
        System.out.println(result);
```